# Нужна ли запятая в моём случае?

Tags: пунктуация

*Разберемся, когда(,) что нужно будет сдать.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, поскольку *"что"* здесь не союз, открывающий придаточное. Если заменить на *"что-то"* смысл будет не в точности такой же, но очень близкий. Перед *"что-то"* тогда никак рука не повернётся поставить запятую, так же и со *"что"* должно быть.

Примеры из [Нацкорпуса](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE):

> Он знает, не бойся! Знает, когда что нужно… Иван Кузьмич оглянулся на дверь и сказал: ― Не потому я говорю, что боюсь. [Георгий Семенов. Приезд сына (1963)]
>
> Ну, пойду, видно. Когда что нужно помогнуть, позови, приду. И когда из дома все уходили, Ирина бежала к своей новой подруге, делая вид, что ей нужно что-нибудь спросить ее. А в действительности потому, что ей было приятно слушать ее ласковый голос с успокоительными интонациями. [П. С. Романов. Человеческая душа (1926)]
>
> ― не понимая, спрашивала баба. ― Она у тебя грамотная будет; будет уметь читать и писать, сосчитать, когда что нужно, письмо написать… Горничная фыркнула себе в руку. ― Какая ты… [В. А. Слепцов. Трудное время (1865)]

Comment: А что за интересное слово "помогнуть" в Нацкорпусе? Разве там допускаются такие официально не существующие формы слов? Или тогда "помочь" не существовало?

Comment: Ну, "подмогнуть" же есть. А это почти оно. А вообще, в нём просто собраны примеры из литературы, а герои, как известно, могут выражаться как угодно.

Comment: "Как угодно" - но ведь литературным языком. Это на Украине сейчас тенденция выдумывать новые слова. Даже и не знал, что есть слово "подмочь". Как-то очень стрёмно звучит. Лучше: чуть(-чуть) помочь, слегка помочь.

Comment: В любом случае вопросы к автору, а не к Нацкорпусу.

Comment: Это да. Но они ведь обязаны брать образцовые тексты в свою коллекцию. Возможно, что раньше (1926 год) такое слово существовало и было звучащим.